# ZendFramework 2 - how to call zfcUser from the Model class

Tags: zend-framework2

I am trying to call **ZFCUser** from a class within my model but i keep getting this message:

```
Call to undefined method Members\Model\MemberTable::zfcUserAuthentication()
```

**this is how i tried to call it:**

```
public function getUserEntity()
    {
        if($this->zfcUserAuthentication()->getAuthService()->hasIdentity())
        {
            if (!$this->user_entity) 
            {
                $this->setUserEntity($this->zfcUserAuthentication()->getAuthService()->getIdentity());
            }
            return $this->user_entity;
        }
    }
```

i suspect that i need to implement/extend a class inorder for ZFcuser to be recoginised.

i would really appriciate some quick advice on this.

thank you

**by the way**

the ZFCUser works when i call it from my controller so, the use Zend\Mvc\Controller\AbstractActionController obviouly enables this to be recoginised.

but what is the equivalent of the AbstractActionController for other classes in your framework.

Answer (score 1):

`zfcUserAuthentication()` is a controller plugin, so that's why it can be called from controllers. You can't (or shouldn't) try and access this from non-controllers. If you need the user entity within another class, you should pass it in as a dependency for that class.

**Edit**: Update your member table factory so it sets the user entity:

```
'Members\Model\MemberTable' => function($sm) {
    $tableGateway = $sm->get('MemberTableGateway');
    $table = new MemberTable($tableGateway);

    $authService = $serviceLocator->get('zfcuser_auth_service');
    $userEntity = $authService->getIdentity();

    $table->setUserEntity($userEntity);

    return $table;
}
```

add a property to your `MemberTable` class for it:

```
protected $userEntity;
```

and getters/setter for it:

```
public function setUserEntity($userEntity)
{
    $this->userEntity = $userEntity;
}

public function getUserEntity()
{
    return $this->userEntity;
}
```

then just call `$this->getUserEntity()` when you need it.

Comment: Hello again tim. thanks for the advice, i understand now. quick question. when you say dependency,how would you recommend feeding this value into the other module ?.

Comment: Hi again Tim Kunal seems to have given good advice on how to access the service locator from the model. May i please ask why you think its not advisable to access it from the Model. i am still trying to learn the correct way to work with Zend. so, i would really appreciate others views on these issues

Comment: He's suggesting you inject the whole service locator into the MemberTable, so you can use that to get the controller plugin manager, and use that to get the zfc user auth plugin, then use that to get the auth service, and then use that to get the user entity. Why not just inject the user entity into the MemberTable in the first place? This is easier to do, the code is clearer, and it's easier to test. I've updated my answer.

Comment: hey tim. thanks for the answer. it does indeed look simpler to call it your way. last question. will i still neeed to use the : class MemberTable implements ServiceLocatorAwareInterface {    //Modified Line
     ....
     .....
}

Comment: i mean, how will the setUserEntity($userEntity) know that the entity is being set unless i use some sort of ServiceLocatorAwareInterface

Comment: No, you don't need `ServiceLocatorAwareInterface`. All you're doing is calling the `setUserEntity()` method which you defined in the class.

Answer (score 0):

There are various ways to do that -

One of the way is - do the following in "MemberTable.php" file.

Maybe most of the below lines of code is already available in our project.

a. Add the below lines after 'namespace' statement -

```
use Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceLocatorAwareInterface;         //Added Line
use Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceLocatorInterface;              //Added Line
```

b. Change the class statement as -

```
class MemberTable implements ServiceLocatorAwareInterface {    //Modified Line
     ....
     .....
}
```

c. Add the below line at  the top of the class statement -

```
class MemberTable implements ServiceLocatorAwareInterface {
     protected $serviceLocator;                                //Added line
     ....
     .....
}
```

d. Add the following functions -

```
public function setServiceLocator(ServiceLocatorInterface $serviceLocator) {
    $this->serviceLocator = $serviceLocator;
}

public function getServiceLocator() {
    return $this->serviceLocator;
}
```

e. In Members/Module.php, make the changes,

```
'Members\Model\MemberTable' => function($sm) {
    $tableGateway = $sm->get('MemberTableGateway');
    $table = new MemberTable($tableGateway);
    $table->setServiceLocator($sm);                   //This is the important line.
    return $table;
}
```

Now you have the 'ServiceLocator' available in the MemberTable class.

For accessing the `zfcUserAuthentication()` or any ControllerPlugin, you can do the following -

```
public function getUserEntity()
{
    $zfcUserAuth = $this->getServiceLocator()->get('controllerPluginManager')->get('zfcUserAuthentication');

    if($zfcUserAuth->getAuthService()->hasIdentity())
    {
        if (!$this->user_entity) 
        {
            $this->setUserEntity($zfcUserAuth->getAuthService()->getIdentity());
        }
        return $this->user_entity;
    }
}
```

Comment: Just FYI, the `$table->setServiceLocator($sm);` should not be necessary, as the service locator aware initializer should call that for you.

Comment: hi Kunal. thanks for the code. quick question. in e, what is $tableGateway = $sm->get('MemberTableGateway');. i mean, what is the  'MemberTableGateway'

Comment: I am using TableGateway instead of any ORM (eg. Doctrine or such) for executing my queries.

Comment: So I have to do the Dependency Injection of the TableGateway object into the ModelTable (via Constructor) which I am using for the queries.
In your case the "MemberTable" class. 

You may or may not be needing such object injection. 
(What I have mentioned is the default usage of the TableGateway)

Comment: For ref:
http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.3/en/user-guide/database-and-models.html

Comment: Hi, Tim is correct about minimizing the code. I just wanted to let you know that in ZF2, how one can create instance of such Services in Model Class or other Service Class. It may be a lengthy process but it has its own pros and cons.